# Can I do parallel processing in Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

I recently got to work with Arduino and I want to get parallel input from 5 LDRs and at the same instance I need to light a LED corresponding to that LDR if the resistance got high.

I read about a finite state machine, but I couldn't understand how it works.

Is it the only way for this type of problem or are there any other way?

Comment: See [How to do multiple things at once](http://www.gammon.com.au/blink)

Comment: For info on state machines, take a look at [What kind of problems are state machines good for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602/what-kind-of-problems-are-state-machines-good-for).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need parallel processing or finite-state machines for that:

```
// Vector with digital pin numbers for LEDs (with resistor to ground)
const int LED_MAX = 5;
const int LED[LED_MAX] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

// Vector with analog pin numbers for LDR (with pullup resistor)
const int LDR_MAX = 5;
const int LDR[LDR_MAX] = { A0, A1, A2, A3, A4 };

// Analog value or lower when to light the LED
const int THRESHOLD = 200;

void setup()
{
   // All LED pins should be digital output pins
   for (int i = 0; i < LED_MAX; i++) 
     pinMode(LED[i], OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
   // Read all LDRs and set LED pins according to threshold
   for (int i = 0; i < LDR_MAX; i++)
     digitalWrite(LED[i], analogRead(LDR[i]) < THRESHOLD);
}
```

But if you really want to describe this as multiple tasks you could use the [Simple Scheduler library](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-Scheduler):

```
#include <Scheduler.h>

const int THRESHOLD = 200;    

template<int LED> void setup()
{
   pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

template<int LED, int LDR> void loop()
{
   digitalWrite(LED, analogRead(LDR) < THRESHOLD);
   yield();
}

void setup()
{
   Scheduler.start(setup<2>, loop<2, A0>);
   Scheduler.start(setup<3>, loop<3, A1>);
   Scheduler.start(setup<4>, loop<4, A2>);
   Scheduler.start(setup<5>, loop<5, A3>);
   Scheduler.start(setup<6>, loop<6, A4>);
}

void loop()
{
   yield();
}
```